# WebRTC: P2P videocall and text/data channels simultaneously?

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

Is it possible to communicate two devices over mobile networks and stablish simultaneous video/audio and data channels over a peer to peer connection? Can it be done without relay or broker servers?

Do you know of any existing project doing this?

Comment: Yes. Any basic WebRTC example can help. You would need a web page or  a link that would be accessible by all peers - some kind of signaling server. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a peer to peer connexion. You only need a server to create a link between the two browsers, just look at ICE server.
There are a lot pf example of webRTC calls with android.
The first example i found [AndroidRTC](https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC)